# Proof by induction that fibonacci sequence are coprime

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have a bit difficulty to proofe that two consecutive numbers are coprime. I have the following

The property $P(n)$ is the equation $(F_{n+1},F_n)=1$ where F_i the sequence of fibonacci is and $n \in \mathbb {N}$.

**Induction hypothesis:** $gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)=1$

$P(0)$ is true because $F_1=1, F_0=1$ and $gcd(1,1)=1$

**To show:** $gcd(F_{n+2},F_{n+1})=1$

**Proof:**

Fibonacci formula says

$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$

This is as faar as I got. How can I now get to $gcd(F_{n+2},F_{n+1})=gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)$ which would then proofe it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+2}) = \gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+1}+F_n) = \gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)$

By the induction hypothesis $\gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)=1$ so $\gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+2})=1$

To prove $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b-a)$ use the fact that if $c\vert a$ and $c\vert b$ then $c\vert na+mb$

Comment: +1 for the third line (the two others are already in the question).